# Improving Python Palindrome code

Tags: python, palindrome, simplify

So I recently implemented a code that checks a word to see if it's a palindrome.

```
def isPalindrome():
    string = input('Enter a string: ')
    string1 = string[::-1]
    if string[0] == string[(len(string)-1)] and string[1:(len(string)-2)] == string1[1:(len(string)-2)]:
            print('It is a palindrome')
    else:
        print('It is not a palindrome')
isPalindrome()
```

I was wondering if anyone could give me tips on simplifying the code.

Edit - If I were to make the function an iterative function with the statements `string == string1`, how would I stop the endless while loop?  Would I need a count to stop the while loop?

Comment: What do you think, that `string[::-1]` does?

Comment: For questions like this (**working code** in want of review), http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is a good place.  stack overflow is really meant for issues with code that doesn't work

Comment: @steve So you know that gives you reverse of the string. Then why would you need the `if-else` condition? You have got the original string, you have got the reverse of that string. Just compare them.

Comment: As a small note it might be considered more "idiomatic" to return the boolean expression (`a == b and x == y`)...then in your "main" program, do `if isPalindrome(): print; else: print`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need for such complex conditional. You already have a reversed string (`string[::-1]`).

All you need to do is this:

```
def isPalindrome():
    string1 = input('Enter a string: ')
    string2 = string1[::-1]
    if string1 == string2:
        return 'It is a palindrome'
    return 'It is not a palindrome'

isPalindrome()
```

(by the way don't use `string` as a variable name. That's the name of a built-in module)

It's better to *return* the strings instead of printing them. That way your function will not `return None` (preventing some stuff that could happen later)

Comment: it doesn't take in account the fact that some words may have accents. Technically, to be considered as palindrome accents, spaces (in case of sentences) are ignored.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in a one liner:

```
return "Is a palindrome" if string == string[::-1] else "Not a palindrome"
```

Sample script:

```
>>> string = "stanleyyelnats"
>>> print "Is a Palindrome" if string == string[::-1] else "Not a palindrome"
>>> Is a Palindrome
```

You can also do this (although its slower):

```
print "Is a Palindrome" if string == ''.join(reversed(string)) else "Not a palindrome"
```

Also, use `raw_input` and not `input`. Because `input` will be *evaluated*. Let me show you an example:

## Script

```
inp = input("Evaluate ")

print inp
```

## Run

```
Evaluate "cheese" + "cake"
cheesecake
```

Comment: Pretty sure OP is using python 3 though

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution in just 1 LINE.

`plandrom = lambda string: True if string == string[::-1] else False`

Answer (score 0):

Please check this algorithm,

```
def is_palindrome(n):
   m = len(n)/2
   for i in range(m):
      j = i + 1
      if n[i] != n[-j]:
         return False
   return True

print is_palindrome('malayayalam')
```

Answer (score 0):

So, I just got into learning python and I have been trying to [these exercises](http://www.ling.gu.se/~lager/python_exercises.html), #8. Though I see that a lot of these answers are creating a new reverse string(which adds a memory overhead) and comparing both strings, I thought I could utilize lesser memory by doing this:

```
def is_palindrome(s):
    l=len(s)
    list_s=list(s)
    for i in range(0,l):                                            
        if(list_s[i] !=list_s[l-i-1]):
            return False
    else:
        return True
```

You can use a print statement to verify.
All I am doing is comparing the first index to the last and the second index to the second last and so on.
Hope that helps.

Comment: This is **incorrect**! Because of the `return True`, once the first character is compared to the last character, the function returns immediately, and the rest of the string is skipped. I just tested this and is_palindrome('HelloH') returns True, even though it is clearly not a palindrome.

Comment: I have changed the else statement from my earlier code and it works fine now. Let me know if you still find this incorrect.

Comment: Yes, this should be OK now, I have removed my downvote.

Comment: As a separate comment, you can also use `range(0, l/2)` as a small optimization. If the first half matches the back half, then you can stop once you get to the middle, you don't need to also check the back half matches the first half.

Comment: Yes, thank you! I have only implemented it as a practice python exercise. Thank you for suggesting the optimization and correcting my program. :)

Comment: What is the reason for `list_s=list(s)`, why not work directly on s?

Answer (score 0):

Check Counter from collections

```
from collections import Counter

def is_palindrome(letters):
    return len([v for v in Counter(letters).values() if v % 2]) <= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution I came up with:

```
###Piece of code to find the palindrome####
def palindrome():
    Palindromee = input("Enter the palindrome \t:")
    index = 0
    length = len(Palindromee)
    while index < length:
         if Palindromee[0] == Palindromee[-1] :
               index +=1
    print ("Palindrome worked as expected")       

palindrome()
```

Comment: Definitely a piece of code. Could be more useful though with a bit of explanation.

Comment: Your loop compares the first and last elements in the input string only, since you've hard-coded the indices `0` and `-1`. Definitely a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to write palindrome

```
a=raw_input("Enter the string : ")    # Ask user input

b= list(a)                            # convert the input into a list

print list(a)

b.reverse()                           # reverse function to reverse the 
                                      # elements of a list

print b

if list(a) == b:                      # comparing the list of input with b

   print("It is a palindrome")

else:

   print("It is not a palindrome")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can as well try this

```
def palindrome(str1):
    return str1==str1[::-1]
print(palindrome(str1)
```

the answer above returns a boolean according to the string given
if it is a palindrome prints true else false

Answer (score 0):

we could use reverse String function to verify Palindrome:

```
def palindrome(s):
    str=s[::-1]
    if s==str:
        return True
    else:
        return False

palindrome('madam')
```